# led analyser for pcb functional test

Tags: led, pcb, test

i'm supposed to work on a project that consists on creating a led analyser to test PCB (**functional test**) 
they want me to create a system that can measure the **color (R,G,B)** and the **luminous intensity** of the LEDs
i choosed to work with this sensor [tcs34725](http://adafruit.com/product/1334) from adafruit.
and probably i'm going to work with arduino

but i have a problem understanding the concept of this project because i'm a transmission engineer not an electrical engineer
why we use leds to test pcb , what information can one interpret from the color (rgb) and luminous intensity of the LEDs
i know it has a relation with the Power consumption, but i can't find anything on the internet that details this topic

Comment: You need to understand how the board under test uses LEDs. Don't ask us - ask the people you work with.

Comment: they just Power the board and test the LED

Comment: They are probably doing the test either for saftey reasons (it is critical that the LED works), for quality control purposes (the led is used for aesthetic purposes) or they want some kind of color calibration. We cannot tell you the reason 'why' they need to measure color or intensity.

Comment: If the LED is illuminated with PWM you will probably have issues measuring something approximating what a human eye would see.

Comment: Often for this kind of test what you can do is set bounds; don't worry about perception, measure a good one and then fail anything that is not some fraction of that reading (too much output could also be a failure, depends on your concerns).  But first make sure you're "seeing" the LED and not room lighting.  If the sensor picks up LED PWM, you'll either need to low pass filter the reading in hardware or software, or look at both the peaks and the duty cycle in your test.

Comment: Supplementary information for other readers here: The OP has asked the same question [here on All About Circuits](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/led-analyser-for-pcb-functional-test.136293/). There is also more background about this project in the OP's previous questions on that forum [here](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/multi-sensor-network-with-arduino-mega-without-using-a-multiplexer-or-a-decoder.132833/) and [here](https://forum.allaboutcircuits.com/threads/multi-sensor-network.132783/).

Comment: You asked us, "what information can one interpret from the color (rgb) and luminous intensity of the LEDs", but you won't ask the folks who want you to do it? What do _they_ expect to learn?

Answer (score 1):

This type of test is commonly done to ensure that the PCBA manufacturer populated the board correctly. This means that they put red LEDs where the red LEDs belong, and the correct brightness is achieved from the LED. I've used RGB sensors like that one previously; the only issue is that they don't have configurable I2C addresses so if you need to measure a bunch of LEDs then it's more difficult. But they're nice because they give you intensity of RGB and clear.

In production you'll want to turn on the LED, wait a millisecond or so for it to settle, and then read the color values. Compare this with a known good board and you will know whether the device is working correctly or not.

There are also integrated solutions like this one, which may be easier if you don't need to build a ton of them:
http://www.finntestelectronics.com/product/smart-finn/

Answer (score 0):

The luminous intensity of an LED (or any light source) is based on the perception of brightness by the human eye. It is measured at a specified solid angle in a specified direction. When dealing with LEDs, the luminous intensity can be affected by the die manufacturing process; the location on the dye from which the chip was taken; the placement and bonding of the LED chip in the carrier; the tint, opacity and diffusion of encapsulating epoxy; the geometry of the epoxy; the angular placement of the LED in the PCB; and the current level and pulse width used to drive the LED.

Many of the LED manufacturer controlled factors are addressed through "binning" whereby the manufacturer grades the LEDs based on various qualities and delivers agreed upon, sorted, and identified bins.

The color of a monochromatic LED is primarily based on the die composition and subsequent binning by the vendor. The encapsulating epoxy has no effect on the color temperature.